# Merge Json Objects in python?

Tags: python, json

I have two json objects. Both may have common keys, Some present only in first object, while some present only in second.
When I come these two objects the structure of objects should not change. Only a new level of keys will be added such as the specifying for which object that value belongs to. Even the structure of json objects represent a hierarchy whose levels are not fixed.

```
a = {"parent1" : { "childa1" : { "grandchilda11" : { "data": values}, 
                                 "grandchilda12" :{"data" : values }
                                }
                               "data" : values 
                 }
                 { "childa2" : { "grandchilda21" : { "data": values}, 
                                 "grandchilda22" :{"data" : values }
                                }
                               "data" : values 
                 }                  
     }
b = { "parent1" : { "childa1" : { "grandchilda11" : { "data": values}, 
                             "grandchilda12" :{"data" : values }
                            }
                           "data" : values 
             }
             { "childa2" : { "grandchilda21" : { "data": values}, 
                             "grandchilda22" :{"data" : values }
                            }
                           "data" : values 
             },
     "parent2" : { "childb1" : { "grandchildb11" : { "data": values}, 
                             "grandchildb12" :{"data" : values }
                            }
                           "data" : values 
             }
             { "childb2" : { "grandchildb21" : { "data": values} 

                            }
                           "data" : values 
             }

 }
```

The resultant should combine this type of json string . The data level here contains directly values while in the resultant it should be like which object it belongs acting as key and then values .

```
 "data" : { "a" : values , "b":values}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what `values` is supposed to be: the whole data dictionary, or perhaps the already existing `'data'` key? If the latter, what is the expected behavior? Flattening the values?

Comment: You don't have  "two json objects", you have two  `dict`. Plain old Python dicts. Most used type in the language, very well documented.  Now could you please edit your question with at least 1. a **complete** example of inputs and expected outputs for these inputs ("values" is not a complete example) and 2. what you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you're looking for.

If you have data dictionaries `a` and `b` you can call the below function using `merge(a, b)` to merge the two like you've said. *It does rely on the assumption that both dictionaries have the same structure to them*.

```
def merge(a, b):
    if type(a) is str:
        return { 'a': a, 'b': b }

    else:
        for key in a:
            a[key] = merge(a[key], b[key])

    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def merge(obj1, obj2):
for key in obj2:
    obj1[key] = obj2[key]
return obj1
```